# What are my (free) options for hosting my Office add-in web-app?

Tags: office365, office-js, web-deployment, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am building an Outlook add-in for my employer to adapt Outlook's functionality more to their needs. In order to deploy the add-in, the .html and .js files need to be hosted somewhere.

Microsoft's documentation recommends to use their Azure service to host. This is not desirable as we are a small company and cannot justify paying $45/month for some basic extra Outlook functionality.

We would also prefer that the add-in is not hosted on the public web as that would cause potential security concerns.

We have a small on-site server, could it be hosted on there somehow?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Talking about the free reliable options for static site hosting.
Here is the list of providers that I know.

**sorted based on reliability and ease of deployment**

1. [Github Pages](https://pages.github.com/)
2. [Google Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/)
3. [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/)
4. [Vercel](https://vercel.com/)
5. [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/)
6. AWS S3 and Amplify